# How to delete an object from a library with ORCA?

Tags: powerbuilder, orca

I need to delete some objects from some specific libraries i have found with a utility i developed in PowerBuilder but thereis no easy way i can delete objects through script.

There is **ORCA** which i never used before and have no idea how to use it.

I am reading the **ORCA** GUIDE but there is no complete example of "**LibraryEntryDelet**"

My utility returns me the objects location which i want to pass to the **LibraryEntryDelet** method to delete the objects.

Can someone help me with sample code for **LibraryEntryDelet**?

*PB12.x*

Answer (score 0):

I know, thats an old Question, but maybe somebody look on this.

There are some inspiration in C#;

```
public class Orca
{
// Orca Session
 [DllImport("pborc170.dll", EntryPoint = "PBORCA_SessionOpen", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static unsafe extern int PBORCA_SessionOpen170();

//Session close
   [DllImport("pborc170.dll", EntryPoint = "PBORCA_SessionClose", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static unsafe extern void PBORCA_SessionClose170(int hORCASession);

// Entry Delete
  [DllImport("pborc170.dll", EntryPoint = "PBORCA_LibraryEntryDelete", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static unsafe extern int PBORCA_LibraryEntryDelete170(int hORCASession, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszLibName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszEntryName, PBORCA_TYPE otEntryType);

//set the entry type enums
 private enum PBORCA_ENTRY_TYPE
        {
            PBORCA_APPLICATION,
            PBORCA_DATAWINDOW,
            PBORCA_FUNCTION,
            PBORCA_MENU,
            PBORCA_QUERY,
            PBORCA_STRUCTURE,
            PBORCA_USEROBJECT,
            PBORCA_WINDOW,
            PBORCA_PIPELINE,
            PBORCA_PROJECT,
            PBORCA_PROXYOBJECT,
            PBORCA_BINARY
        }

public static void LibraryEntryDelete(string pbl= "blabla.pbl", string entry = "blablaDatawindow", PBORCA_ENTRY_TYPE entryType= PBORCA_ENTRY_TYPE.PBORCA_DATAWINDOW)
{

//Open Session
    int orcaSession = PBORCA_SessionOpen170();

//delete entry
       PBORCA_LibraryEntryDelete170(orcaSession, pbl, entry, entryType);

//close session
    PBORCA_SessionClose170(orcaSession );
}

}
```

There is a massive potential with ORCA functions in .NET. Maybe look at the PBDotNet project at github for more claritiy.